# Cant edit any config file in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I try to open any kind of .config files in Visual Studio but I dont see the XML Content, I only get a blank blue window with no content.
I only have Resharper 6 (with Agent Johnson) and Nuget installed.
Does anybody knows this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same behaviour. I used a trial of Resharper 6 and disabled that. From that moment I cannot open XML-files in the visual studio editor anymore. VS takes ages and 50% CPU to decide that it won't show the content of xml and xml-based files (such as web.config).

Didn't find any decent solution.

I finally decided to give the repair option of the VS installer a try. After repair of VS I re-enabled SP1 and now I'm able to edit xml files in VS. Everything seems to run smooth. Other plugins still work and I cannot find anything broken.

This is the first time that I did a repair of VS. I'm not utterly convinced that the repair function and re-enabling of SP1 is sufficient for a complete restore of VS. But so far so good. Keeping my fingers crossed, virtually.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you deleted the content of the config files without realizing? Check your repository for changes to see if any modifications were made.

Also try opening the file with another text editor to check if the file contains anything at all.

Comment: Thats the strange thing there is content with any other editor except Visual Studio. I only get the "Tab" for the file but the content window doesnt seem to appear.